# Can I ask questions based on some other website / authors work?

Tags: discussion

Is it appropriate to ask questions based on other people's work?

I found this really cool sci-fi invention on someone else's page.  Can I post the material here and ask for a second opinion?  Should I cite the work somehow?

Comment: Can you clarify: What do you mean by "other people's work"? If you mean Star Trek or Star Wars kind of thing, then I'd agree with L. Dutch's closure as duplicate. Your wording suggests that you're not referring to a commercial or public intellectual property. If for example you found some really cool invention that *I'd* written about, that would be more appropriately asked about here. If this is the case, I think a clarifying edit and a reopening would be in order.